# Kotlin - same condition: multiple if statements or one if statement

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin you can use if statements kind of like ternary operators.

We have the option to do something like this:

```
val x = if (isOdd) 1 else 2
```

but if we have multiple variables that need to be set based on some condition is it more correct to do it the old fashioned way like so:

```
val x: Int
val y: Int
val z: Int

if (isOdd) {
    x = 1
    y = 3
    z = 5
} else {
    x = 2
    y = 4
    z = 6
}
```

or like this :

```
val x = if (isOdd) 1 else 2
val y = if (isOdd) 3 else 4
val z = if (isOdd) 5 else 6
```

the second way looks much cleaner to me, but I'd like to know if the first method would be computed faster since it only needs to calculate the condition once whereas the second way needs to check the condition 3 times.

Is the second way actually slower or will it be optimized by the compiler?

Comment: It probably depends on whether `isOdd` is a local variable or could theoretically be changed by another thread.

Comment: useless premature optimization

Comment: Performance, at this level, is completely irrelevant. You're talking about a difference of 2 boolean checks. That's billionths of a second. Just pick the one that's most readable, which is a subjective metric.

Comment: Your example can be written like this: `val (x, y, z) = if (isOdd) Triple(1, 3, 5) else Triple(2, 4, 6)`

Comment: @Michael I posted an answer showing there is actually quite a large difference in speed, any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer something like this, looks way more Kotlinesque:

```
data class Point3D(val x: Int, val y: Int, val z: Int)

fun foo(isOdd: Boolean): Point3D = if (isOdd) Point3D(1, 3, 5) else Point3D(2, 4, 6)

//or using destructureing see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html)
val (x,y,z) = if (isOdd) Triple(1, 3, 5) else Triple(2, 4, 6)
```

Also it combines the best of both, using `if` as expression and only one `if` is needed. (At the cost of an additional object allocation).

But to answer your question. Do what you like and think is most readable. Performance wise I doubt you will make a difference.

Comment: just because his example has x,y,z doesn't mean he wants to compute 3D points

Comment: @TimCastelijns well you could also use [`Triple`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-triple/index.html) instead of a custom `data class`. I just put in a name that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

`if` is an expression in Kotlin, not a statement: it returns a value, whereas it doesn't in Java's case.

I don't think here is such an optimization issue you should ever think about, honestly. Premature optimization is a common source of problems. If this boolean variable is thread-confined, then I think the compiler will perform all the optimizations that are possible in this context, so it will be almost no overhead at all (if not completely).

Wise choice in OO languages is to prefer clearness and flexibility over low-level optimization issues (especially when compilers are able to resolve them).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so just saw this question again and got curious... So I did some tests.

Turns out there is actually a HUGE difference, heres the results:

Code

```kotlin
fun main() {
    for (i in 0 until 3) {
        val t1_s = System.currentTimeMillis()
        for (j in 0 until 100000) {
            when (i){
                0 -> a(j % 2 == 0)
                1 -> b(j % 2 == 0)
                2 -> c(j % 2 == 0)
            }
        }
        val t1_e = System.currentTimeMillis()
        println("Test $i - time ${t1_e - t1_s}")
    }
}

fun a(isOdd: Boolean): Int {
    val x: Int
    val y: Int
    val z: Int

    if (isOdd) {
        x = 1
        y = 3
        z = 5   
    } else {
        x = 2
        y = 4
        z = 6
    }
    
    return x + y + z
}

fun b(isOdd: Boolean): Int {
    val x = if (isOdd) 1 else 2
    val y = if (isOdd) 3 else 4
    val z = if (isOdd) 5 else 6
    
    return x + y + z
}

fun c(isOdd: Boolean): Int {
    val (x,y,z) = if (isOdd) Triple(1, 3, 5) else Triple(2, 4, 6)
    
    return x + y + z
}
```

Output

```
Test 0 - time 3
Test 1 - time 1
Test 2 - time 8
```

It seems my second solution is the fastest, my first suggestion next, and the top answer as MUCH slower.

Does any one know why this might be? Obviously these are milliseconds so it almost always wouldn't matter, but it is neat to think that one method is 5-10 times faster

EDIT:

So tried  bumptin the iterations up to 100000000 and the results were:

```
Test 0 - time 6
Test 1 - time 41
Test 2 - time 941
```

I Guess the first 2 options are getting optimized out but the third option is always creating a new object making it much slow

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDLbsIwEDzjrxghKsUiVHkAByR66K2HqodyrwIY1a1xUOK0SVC@PbVjHokQ0D1Emd3x7Mx@x0pwWdebTGIbcelQ7Al0beIEDgeX8JBJxQXC48jUTySg/I8Uc7wXqWLbx1WWJEyqBd@yVy4ETx16YjdiX20x3zPVVjT1@8mk3kq7XVMeRk@ItMYDAszn8OgFxTeU5U1KYCirq5SKXP4dgrL/Bd0lXCohnf6CpQoDjhGU5mGwbzRGzc2qvn1QkYoQc/jI4enbej3DcxwLFkk6w4tUh9sYA3nTOMGiC0sLG8w3sGLH0/Zy7dw/GSw0Cg3qlfpv0rNGwETK2g@ChmLIY9s07Ck5n6b5JExliUSOodYdojzmWd7No9VaTn27PzgH7M5DOx@fE3fnEzuf3ne2uufMyd3CLWlXf5HwnWCO7yJ0MaF226EZuBi7mNJbu0FIXf8B)

Comment: 35ms / 100 million operations = 0.35 nanoseconds. I dispute that that's a "HUGE difference". That's the same time it takes light to travel 10 centimeters.